# It takes a long time to compare two table values (large volume)

Tags: postgresql

Table a has 100 row with name columns.
Table b is the same structure as Table A, but has 10 million rows.
Create a query to verify that the value of table a is not in table b.
However, comparing the value of table a with the value of table b takes too long.
I want to complete the work in 5 seconds, but I don't know how.
Below is the method I tried. Both table name columns have b-tree indexes.

1.

```
select 
    name
from 
    a
where  
    and not exists (select 
                        name
                    from 
                        b 
                    where 
                        a.name = b.name
                   );
```

2. 

```
select
    a.name
from 
    a left outer join b
    on a.name = b.name
where
    b.name is null;
```

Comment: Both of those queries should finish in a tiny fraction of 5 seconds.  Please show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for them, preferably after turning on track_io_timing.

Comment: The name looks like a simple column, but it is a random string such as 'oifeshf65344'. That's why it's taking a long time.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it should still be fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the following index on the B table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX name_idx ON b (name);
```

This should allow Postgres to rapidly lookup any of the 100 names in the `a` table against the above index.  This should avoid the need to do a full table scan of the `b` table, which, as you are seeing, can be costly.

Comment: You have already completed index setup for table b. The value in the name column is a rather complex string, such as 'fsdfseg434432'. So I think it will take a long time.

Comment: The complexity of the string isn't really the issue, rather it is the _cardinality_ (uniqueness) and also size of the `b` table which matter.